# Masking NetCDF data using shapefile (xarray & geopandas)

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, geopandas, rioxarray

I am using the following packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import geopandas as gpd
```

I have the following objects storing data:

```
print(precip_da)

Out[]:
    <xarray.DataArray 'precip' (time: 13665, latitude: 200, longitude: 220)>
    [601260000 values with dtype=float32]
    Coordinates:
      * longitude  (longitude) float32 35.024994 35.074997 35.125 35.175003 ...
      * latitude   (latitude) float32 5.0249977 5.074997 5.125 5.174999 ...
      * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1981-01-01 1981-01-02 1981-01-03 ...
    Attributes:
        standard_name:       convective precipitation rate
        long_name:           Climate Hazards group InfraRed Precipitation with St...
        units:               mm/day
        time_step:           day
        geostatial_lat_min:  -50.0
        geostatial_lat_max:  50.0
        geostatial_lon_min:  -180.0
        geostatial_lon_max:  180.0
```

This looks as follows:

```
precip_da.mean(dim="time").plot()
```

[image: Mean precipitation over NE Ethiopia]

I have my shapefile as a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` which represents a polygon.

```
awash = gpd.read_file(shp_dir+"/Export_Output.shp")

awash
Out[]:
  OID_         Name      FolderPath  SymbolID  AltMode Base  Clamped Extruded  Snippet PopupInfo Shape_Leng  Shape_Area  geometry
0     0 Awash_Basin Awash_Basin.kml         0        0  0.0       -1        0     None      None  30.180944    9.411263  POLYGON Z ((41.78939511000004 11.5539922500000...
```

Which looks as follows:

```
awash.plot()
```

[image: Region shapefile stored as geopandas.GeoDataFrame]

Plotted one on top of the other they look like this:

```
ax = awash.plot(alpha=0.2, color='black')
precip_da.mean(dim="time").plot(ax=ax,zorder=-1)
```

[image: Awash Region superimposed on precipitation data]

My question is, how do I mask the `xarray.DataArray` by checking if the lat-lon points lie INSIDE the shapefile stored as a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`?

So I want ONLY the precipitation values (mm/day) which fall INSIDE that shapefile.

I want to do something like the following:

```
masked_precip = precip_da.within(awash)
```

OR

```
masked_precip = precip_da.loc[precip_da.isin(awash)]
```

**EDIT**

I have thought about using the `rasterio.mask` [module](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html) but I don't know what format the input data needs to be. It sounds as if it does exactly the right thing:

"*Creates a masked or filled array using input shapes. Pixels are masked or set to nodata outside the input shapes*"

Comment: masked_output = rasterio.mask.mask(precip_da.mean(dim="time"), awash) should work fine?

Comment: Even if I want to apply it to across all times? So that's fine for the mean but there are `13665` timesteps and I need the whole `xarray.DataArray` to be masked. I can update the question if not clear! Thank you very much though

Comment: Then you'd have to loop over each timestep and append to a new xarray OR you can try rasterio.mask.mask(precip_da.values, awash) to see if the mask can be completed on the 3D xarray directly.

Comment: I seem to get the following error running the first piece of code (`masked_output = rasterio.mask.mask(precip_da.mean(dim="time"), awash)  `). The error was: `AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'nodata'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mask NetCDF time series data from a shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

You can use rioxarray. Here is an example: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas

geodf = geopandas.read_file(...)
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [regionmask](https://regionmask.readthedocs.io) does what you want.

> regionmask is a Python module that:
>
> - contains a number of defined regions, including: countries, a landmask and regions used in the scientific literature.
> - can plot figures of these regions with matplotlib and cartopy.
> - can be used to create masks of the regions for arbitrary longitude and latitude grids with numpy and xarray
> - arbitrary regions can be defined easily

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Overlay from Geopandas should work as well, through intersection
http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/examples/overlays.ipynb
But you need first: 
1. Convert your netcdf into a dataframe, 
2. convert latitude and longitud into a polygon like in this example, all the way to the end https://medium.com/@Arbolmarket/working-with-geospatial-data-in-python-a5ad984c1161
Or even better, like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332479/store-netcdf-data-in-geodataframe

Comment: Please include a short summary of the links content as they may change in time.